# check if ipod music plays problem

Tags: objective-c, ios4, media-player, nscoder

i want to check if ipod music is played, so i added the mediaplayer framework and imported it:

```
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
```

then i've got in an NSCoder:

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder { 

self = [super initWithCoder:coder];

if(self)
{

    if ([[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer] playbackState] == MPMusicPlaybackStatePlaying) {
    }
    else {

        [self playBgMusic];


    } }

return self; }
```

But this doesn't work. If ipod music is playing and I start the app the ipod music turns off and the music from the app is played.

What's wrong?

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question.

Comment: you're right, i'm sorry it's caused by my tiredness. now there is a question

Answer (score 1):

1. Add AVFoundation framework to your project (if not there already).
2. Import it into your app delegate.

   ```
   #import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
   ```
3. Put this code in your application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method so it gets run on app launch.

   ```
   [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:nil];
   ```

---

This sets the "category" of the audio session your app uses to allow mixing with the iPod music player. By default the category is set to "AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient" which does not allow mixing. See Apple's doc below.

[Working with Movies and iPod Music](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/WorkingWithOpenALiPodMusicandMovies/WorkingWithOpenALiPodMusicandMovies.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH14-SW1)

[AVAudioSession Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/data/AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient)